# How to get a depth image from sparse depth data?

Tags: c++, image, opencv, image-processing, ros

I am currently working on a problem where I have created an uint16 image of type CV_16UC1 based on Velodyne data where lets say 98% of the pixels are black (value 0) and the remaining pixels have the metric depth information (distance to that point). These pixels correspond to the velodyne points from the cloud.

```
cv::Mat depthMat = cv::Mat::zeros(frame.size(), CV_16UC1);
depthMat = ... //here the matrice is filled
```

If I try to display this image I get this:

[image]

On the image you can see that the brightest(white) pixels correspond to the pixels with biggest depth.From this I need to get a denser depth image or smth that would resemble a proper depth image like in the example shown on this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4yZ4JGgLE0I

This would require proper interpolation and extrapolation of those points (the pixels of the 2D image) and it is here is where I am stuck. I am a beginner when it comes to interpolation techniques.  Does anyone know how this can be done or at least can point me to a working solution or example algorithm for creating a depth map from sparse data?

I tried the following from the [Kinect](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u0A4OVZxzKQ) examples but it did not change the output:

```
depthMat.convertTo(depthf, CV_8UC1, 255.0/65535);

const unsigned char noDepth = 255;
cv::Mat small_depthf, temp, temp2;
cv::resize(depthf, small_depthf, cv::Size(), 0.01, 0.01);

cv::inpaint(small_depthf, (small_depthf == noDepth), temp, 5.0, cv::INPAINT_TELEA);

cv::resize(temp, temp2, depthf.size());

temp2.copyTo(depthf, (depthf == noDepth));
cv::imshow("window",depthf);
cv::waitKey(3);
```

Comment: Remember: only you have the data to test and make this spaghetti code work. 99.9% of the people here don't have a Velodyne sensor sitting on a desk. With that in mind, realize that the way the question is written right now means nobody is going to be able to help you. Good luck!

Comment: On a side note, I noticed you asked a few questions and haven't selected any official answer for them. It seems that at least a few of them deserve to have an answer select. Can you go back, review your questions and click on the checkbox near the answer that best solved those problems? This will give a few points to the guys that answer them and help us keep Stackoverflow organized. In the future, people with similar problems will read your question and find the best answer more easily if they are marked as so.

Comment: @karlphillip You are right, I edited the title to make no confusion with Velodyne since the problem can be just rephrased as "how to do  interpolation/extrapolation on sparse depth 2D image". We are dealing only with a one channel image matrix here. As for the previous questions that I somehow neglected I gave them a review, thx for reminding me to do that :)

Comment: Have you [seen this](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.1/df/d3d/tutorial_py_inpainting.html)? The mask has to be thicker/larger than the lines that degrade the original image. I don't think you are doing this correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get the desired output(something that resembles a depth image) by simply using dilation on the sparse depth image:

```
cv::Mat result;
dilate(depthMat, result, cv::Mat(), cv::Point(-1, -1), 10, 1, 1);
```